# Python: Convert a byte array back to list of int

Tags: python, arrays

I can convert a list of ints into a byte array with the following:

```
bytes([17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76])
Out[144]: b'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L'
bytes([1, 2, 3])
Out[145]: b'\x01\x02\x03'
```

**What I want now is to get the byte array string back to its original list**. Is there an easy python function to do that? I found the following:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L', byteorder='big', signed=False)
Out[146]: 1231867543503643212
```

I am not quite sure what is happening here. How is the conversion happening and what does the output signify. So if anyone can provide some context or insight, I will be grateful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the bytearray to a list of ints with `list()`

#### Test Code:

```
x = bytes([17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76])
print(x)
print(list(x))
```

#### Results:

```
b'\x11\x18y\x01\x0c\xde"L'
[17, 24, 121, 1, 12, 222, 34, 76]
```

Comment: Easier than I imagined

Comment: Could you also explain what is happening in int.from_bytes if possible

Comment: `int.frombytes()` builds an integer.  It can be big if you pass lots of bytes.